# Исправить регулярку

Tags: php

Регулярка в тексте ищет слова с двумя первыми буквами заглавными а третьей и последующими - в нижнем регистре. И Второй буквы опускает регистр.
Было: ТАк
Стало: Так

Моя регулярка страшная как черт:

```
$in=preg_replace('/\b([A-ZЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ])([A-ZЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ])([a-zёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю].*)\b/e','"$1".strtolower("$2")."$3"',$in,10);
```

К тому же какая-то не совсем рабочая, через раз работает, непонятно почему.
Кто поможет сделать из регулярки - конфету шоколадную ? Однострочником.

Все происходит в кодировке 1251

Answer (score 2):

вот так покороче ([A-ZА-Я])([A-ZА-Я]).+?\s